# Change Zotero Bibliography language in Overleaf

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

I am using Zotero with Overleaf as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\selectlanguage{german}
\printbibliography
```

The result looks fine, since I get a German title for my bibliography and the cites work as expected. The only drawback is that text in my bibliography and the cites in my text are in english (e.g. last visited, author 1 and author 2, ...) but I need them to be in German. I tried to use `\usepackage[german]{babel}` but then I get the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\@ifundefined #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1
                                              \endcsname \relax \expandafter...
l.52 ...Init\CurrentOption{captions\CurrentOption}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Is there any other way to change the cite and bibliography language?

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that consists of a small but compilable test document instead of a code fragment? Please also show us the relevant entries in your .bib file that are necessary to compile your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving into several custom style files, I found `\RequirePackage{german}`. It seems that this causes trouble when including the german babel package. Removing this line solves the error.